# viewModelFactory property has not been initialized in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

So I have an error that says viewModelFactory has not been initialized I tried to search other solutions but it didn't work.

I want to populate data from Room Database and display it on the RecyclerView.

```js
class Edit_Form : Fragment()  {
    lateinit var  photoAdapter: Photo_Adapter
    var dataList = mutableListOf<Plant>()

    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<Photo_Adapter.ViewHolder>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                               container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        lateinit var  photoAdapter: Photo_Adapter
        lateinit var plantViewModel: PlantViewModel

        var dataList = mutableListOf<Plant>()
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit__form, container, false)
        val fab = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton) as FloatingActionButton
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
            
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        photoAdapter = Photo_Adapter(context)
        recyclerView.adapter = photoAdapter

         lateinit var viewModelFactory :PlantViewModelFactory
         plantViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory ).get(PlantViewModel::class.java)
        plantViewModel.allPlants.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
            photoAdapter.setDataList(it)
        })
        fab?.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(view.context, Edit_Form::class.java)
           startActivity(intent);
        }
        return view
    }

}
```

My Viewmodel and ViewModel Factory:

```
public class PlantViewModel(private val repository: PlantRepository):ViewModel() {

    val allPlants: LiveData<List<Plant>> = repository.allPlants.asLiveData()

    fun insert(plant: Plant) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(plant)
    }
}
    class PlantViewModelFactory(private val repository: PlantRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(PlantViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return PlantViewModel(repository) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
        }


}
```

Perhaps I missed the depedency in the build script?

This is my  build gradle script:

```js
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    //Room database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-common:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"

    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2'
    //Lifecycle
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.2.0"
    //Viewmodel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    //LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
    //ui
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    //navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //views
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    //testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
}
```

I will be grateful for your help! :)

Comment: This is happening because you are passing your `viewModelFactory` object to the `ViewModelProvider` without initializing it. Please initialize it using `viewModelFactory = PlantViewModelFactory(somedependencies)` then pass it to the constructor.

Comment: @Jarnojr Then what dependencies should I add? I added the code ViewModelFactory , it say that I need repository I tried to add repository and my code turn red. Sorry it's first time dealing with ViewModels

Comment: You should add what your ViewModel constructor is needed. So in your case, you should first initialize your repository then pass it to the `PlantViewModelFactory` then initialize your ViewModel.